# Possible to update multiple reducer by dispatching single redux action?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

**Disclaimer**: this question is targeting specific package [reduxsauce](https://github.com/infinitered/reduxsauce/issues/new)

Takes classic redux action, by dispatching a single action, it will flow thru all the reducer and if we want to update the state, we catch the type in each and every reducer as we see fit

> loginPage.js

```js
this.props.memberLogin({ name: 'john' }); //{ type: MEMBER_LOGIN, payload: { name: 'john' } }
```

> LoginAction.js

```js
const memberLogin = member => {
  return { type: MEMBER_LOGIN, payload: member }
}
```

> authReducer.js

```js
const INITIAL_STATE = { isLoggedIn: false }

switch(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  case MEMBER_LOGIN: return { ...state, isLoggedIn: true };
  default: return state;
}
```

> memberReducer.js

```js
const INITIAL_STATE = { member: null }

switch(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  case MEMBER_LOGIN: return { ...state, member: action.payload };
  default: return state;
}
```

Wondering by using `reduxsauce`, can we still achieve something similar as demonstrated above? (dispatch single action and update both reducer)

Comment: The one way that I can think of is creating an action which will internally dispatch two different actions which will call these two reducers respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

I created [this Snack example](https://snack.expo.io/B1sfmPssN) to help you, but the gist is that you have to configure your reducers to listen to the same action.

Kinda like so:

```js
const reduceA = (state, action) => ({
  ...state,
  a: action.value,
});

const reduceB = (state, action) => ({
  ...state,
  b: action.value,
});

const { Types, Creators: actionCreators } = createActions({
  testAction: ['value'],
});


const HANDLERS_A = {
  [Types.TEST_ACTION]: reduceA,
};

const HANDLERS_B = {
  [Types.TEST_ACTION]: reduceB,
};
```

In the example both reducers A and B have their state values altered by the same action `testAction`.

Comment: What if they are not in the same file (e.g: `redux_A.js` & `redux_B.js` ), in that case, I will have to export `Types.TEST_ACTION`? Will it actually recognizable?

Comment: @Isaac Yes, it will be recognizable. Just export the `Types` object and use it wherever you want the state to change. I just did it all in one file because it was easier, but if you alter the Snack example it should work with reducers being created in different files.

Comment: @Isaac In one of the projects I work at we defined actions in a separante file called `Actions.js` and imported the `Types` and `Creator` objects. The `Types` object is just a handy shortcut to get the string that identifies the action you want to treat, you could just pass a string to `HANDLERS_A` and it would work fine as long as it identified the correct action.

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/S1cWp3jjN I've separated it but not sure if it's the right way

Comment: Ahhhh....I see your point and starting to get the gist of it now! Thanks a lot Bruno!